# Two Antd forms, one component

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have two antd forms within a single component. The first form is a register form where a user inputs various information (firstname, lastname, email, etc..) The `submit` button triggers a function to open a modal with another form for them to verify their phone number by generating a code that is texted to them. Once the code is typed and they hit verify, it verifies if it is the correct code - then i would like for it to register the user but I am having difficulties pulling in the values from the first form..

Is there a specific way to go about doing this? I thought maybe I could utilize `useState` and set the values to component level state but even that didnt work..

**form**

```
<Form
  layout="vertical"
  name="register-form"
  initialValues={initialValues}
  onFinish={handleVerification}
>
  <Row gutter={ROW_GUTTER}>
    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
      <Form.Item
        name="firstName"
        label="First Name"
        rules={rules.firstName}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter First Name" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
      <Form.Item
        name="lastName"
        label="Last Name"
        rules={rules.lastName}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
  </Row>
  <Row gutter={ROW_GUTTER}>
    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
      <Form.Item
        name="phone"
        label="Phone Number"
        rules={rules.phone}
        hasFeedback
      >
        <Input placeholder="Enter Phone Number" />
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
    <Col xs={24} sm={24} md={12}>
      <Form.Item name="city" label="City" rules={rules.city} hasFeedback>
        <Select placeholder="Select City">
          <Option value="Lancaster, PA">Lancaster, PA</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    </Col>
  </Row>
  <Form.Item
    name="email"
    label="Email Address"
    rules={rules.email}
    hasFeedback
  >
    <Input placeholder="Enter Email Address" />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item
    name="password"
    label="Password"
    rules={rules.password}
    hasFeedback
  >
    <Input.Password placeholder="Enter Password" />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item
    name="confirmPassword"
    label="Confirm Password"
    rules={rules.confirm}
    hasFeedback
  >
    <Input.Password placeholder="Confirm Password" />
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item name="tos" valuePropName="checked">
    <Checkbox>
      I agree to the <Link to="/">Terms of Service</Link> and{' '}
      <Link to="/">Privacy Policy</Link>.
    </Checkbox>
  </Form.Item>
  <Form.Item>
    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" block>
      Register
    </Button>
  </Form.Item>
</Form>

<Modal
  title="Account Verification"
  centered
  visible={modal}
  onOk={() => setModal(false)}
  onCancel={() => setModal(false)}
>
  <p>
    To finish registering, please enter the verification code we just sent
    to your phone. If you didn't receive a code, make sure your entered
    phone number is correct and sign up again. Your code will expire upon
    closing this popup.
  </p>
  <Form layout="vertical" name="verify-phone-form" onFinish={onSubmit}>
    <Form.Item name="enteredCode" label="Verify">
      <Input placeholder="Enter Code" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item>
      <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" block>
        Verify
      </Button>
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

handleVerification

```
const handleVerification = async (values) => {
  const { phone, email } = values;

  setModal(true);
  try {
    const response = await postRegisterCheckDuplicate({ email, phone });

    if (response.data.success) {
      switch (response.data.message) {
        case 0:
          try {
            const response = await dispatch(
              attemptRegisterVerify({ to: phone })
            );
            console.log('handleVerification: ', response.message);
            if (response.success) {
              setGeneratedCode(response.message);
            } else {
              console.log(response.message);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
          break;

        case 1:
          console.log('Email Address already in use.');
          break;
        case 2:
          console.log('Phone number already in use.');
          break;
        case 3:
          console.log('Email and Phone in use.');
          break;
      }
    } else {
      console.log(response.data.message);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

**onSubmit**

```
const onSubmit = (values) => {
  const { enteredCode } = values;
  if (generatedCode === enteredCode) {
    try {
      console.log('values :', values);
      // dispatch(attemptRegister(values));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Verification code incorrect');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a form instance (hooks) and reference it to the first form so you can use the api of the instance. You can check more here [antd FormInstance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)

```
const [registerForm] = Form.useForm();

const handleSubmit = (values) => {
    const { enteredCode } = values;
    console.log(registerForm.getFieldsValue());
    //output is the values in the first form
};

<Form form={registerForm} layout="vertical" onFinish={handleVerification}>
    ...
</Form>
```

I created a small version of your work. See working code here:

[image: Edit prod-http-h73fi]

You can also check this one [antd control between forms](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-form-context)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two form instances.

```
const [form]  = Form.useForm();
const [form2] = Form.useForm();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).